# Movie player embedded in UIWebView did enter fullscreen at iPhone but not at iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, streaming

I have **UIWebView** in my app that plays some streaming media. When I run app on iPhone embedded movie player starts at fullscreen however on iPad it doesn't. Stream stays just inside UIWebView frame.

why is it not playing full screen on iPad? How can I possibly force embedded movie player enter fullscreen?

Comment: mevie player in-sense are you using youtube?

Comment: No, it is custom stream of some local tv. I know how to do it for YouTube but this is different problem. I can solve it by using private api, however, I prefer some clean solution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Just the one with private api.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad doesn't start with fullscreen when playing a movie, you have to change it to fullscreen by clicking the button in the left corner or pinch to zoom.